# Can I delete props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just want to know is it possible to delete react component props safely from the component.

Is there any function like

this.destroyProps({someProp})

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't. The props of a react component are [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and are not supposed to be changed by the component.

If you need to work with the data locally, you could use the [state of the component](https://medium.com/react-tutorials/react-state-14a6d4f736f5), or better create a local copy of the prop data.

Answer (score 3):

If you were passing the props onto a child component, you could create a new object, delete the properties from that and then pass to the child.

```
const childProps = { ...this.props };
delete childProps.someProp;
return (
  <ChildComponent {...childProps} />
)
```

Comment: Actually, a deconstructed assignment is preferred, see the answer by @Petrogad.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just deconstruct the deleted prop out and then you can use the rest?

```
const {someProp, ...rest} = this.props;
return (
    <ChildComponent {...rest} />
);
```

But really, the question here is why you're passing in the `someProp` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

**Typescript to the rescue**

Using [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) (which was added in TS 3.5) you could extend your existing component removing the undesired props.

**Usage:**

```
interface Original {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
    baz: boolean;
}

// Omit a single property:
type OmitFoo = Omit<Original, "foo">; // Equivalent to: {bar: number, baz: boolean}

// Or, to omit multiple properties:
type OmitFooAndBar = Omit<Original, "foo" | "bar">; // Equivalent to: {baz: boolean}
```

We can combine [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) with [Extends](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#extends) to create a new interface we can add our additional props to like so.

**Example:**

say we want to create a button component based on the button component from a 3rd party library but remove some of the props.

```
import {
  Button as ThirdPartyButton,
  ButtonProps as ThirdPartyButtonProps,
} from '<SOME-THIRD-PARTY-LIBRARY>';

export interface ButtonProps extends Omit<ThirdPartyButtonProps, 'someProperty'> {
  /**
   * The content of the component.
   */
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

/**
 * Button Component
 */
const Button = ({ children, ...otherProps }: ButtonProps): JSX.Element => (
  <ThirdPartyButton {...otherProps}>{children}</ThirdPartyButton>
);

export default Button;
```